# C# - Dropdown in repeater not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

```
protected void LoadRecords()
{
    List<PO.viewSO_Result> viewpolist = objDb.viewSO().ToList();

    CustomerRepeater.DataSource = viewpolist;
    CustomerRepeater.DataBind(); 
}
```

That's the .aspx code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="CustomerRepeater" runat="server" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr class="odd gradeX" > 
            <td><%# Eval("Supplier_order_id_pk") %></td> 
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="dropdown1">
                    <asp:ListItem Text='<%# Eval("Supplier_order_id_pk") %>' Value='<%# Eval("Supplier_order_id_pk") %>'></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td> 
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

My DropDown does not work or fetch value. This is the error message:

> Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event. System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem does not have a DataBinding event

I need to create DropDown in repeater using this way.

Comment: Adding `urgent` will not help speed things up. We do not have an SLA with you. And you cannot bind data to `ListItem` as the error states

Comment: help me how to create dropdown in repeater using above c# function and aspx file code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<asp:Repeater ID="CustomerRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="CustomerRepeater_ItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr class="odd gradeX" > 
        <td> <asp:Label ID="lblOrderID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Supplier_order_id_pk") %>'></asp:Label></td> 
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="dropdown1">

            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td> 
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

```
protected void CustomerRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            DropDownList ds = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("dropdown1");
            ds.Items.Add((e.Item.FindControl("lblOrderID") as Label).Text);
        }
    }
```